# regex to identify function calls?

Tags: regex, vb6

I need to identify all types VB6 code when functions are called.

I have tried:

`^(?:(?!\bDim\b).)*(?:(?<functionName>(?:fl|fg)[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(?:(?!\s\=\s).)*$(?:\(?.*\)?|))$`

Samples

```
flProcessar = xmlString
Dim flProcessar
flProcessar()
Call flProcessar
Call flProcessar()
Call flProcessar obj
flProcessar(obj)
flProcessar obj
flProcessar

mdiLQS.uctlogErros.MostrarErros Err, Me.Name & " - flProcessar", Me.Caption
```

The last line will not be matched by the regex above.

Comment: Probably solution.

`^(?:(?!\bDim\b).)(Call|\s|.+=)*(?:(?<functionName>(?:fl|fg)[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(?:(?!\s\=\s).)*$(?:\(?.*\)?|))$`